# AngularJS directive's $scope.var is updated but no class is added. Why? How to fix?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I do not understand what is going on with my `$scope.isYellow` variable. Why it gets updated just fine but class `yellow` isn't added to an element?

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akctq645/

The goal is simple: when you click on a "Color" `span`, it's background has to become yellow. I use `ng-class` and a custom directive to achieve it. My custom directive's scope has appropriate variable `isYellow` for that:

`<span id="spanElem" make-yellow-directive ng-class="{yellow: isYellow}">Color</span>`

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
    $scope.isYellow = 0;
    this.toggleIsYellow = function() {
        $scope.isYellow = ($scope.isYellow == 1) ? 0 : 1;
    }
},
```

But whatever I do, it doesn't work. For some reason the variable `$scope.isYellow` in `this.toggleIsYellow` method gets updated but the `span` doesn't become yellow, `yellow` class is not added. Event if I toggle `$scope.isYellow` manually in Chrome Console debugger, class `yellow` doesn't appear on `span`.

Why? What is going on? It is the same scope, it's `isYellow` variable gets updated but why class `yellow` isn't added to `span`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular's two-way binding is powered by the so called digest cycle. In short, Angular keeps its own event queue and uses it to figure out when it needs to walk the scope tree to check for changes. When you use the jQuery 'on()' function, you're creating an event that doesn't go through the Angular digest cycle, meaning that it won't know that it needs to update the ui to match changes in the scope. A quick fix would be to do this:

```
function onClickHandler(e) {
    console.log('== onClickHandler ==: ', e);
    
    scope.$apply(function () {
        ctrl.toggleIsYellow(e);
    });
};
```

The "$apply" method is used to force Angular to initiate a digest. Though, you should really just use "ng-click" on the span you want to have toggle behavior. Using "$apply" is usually a code-smell in Angular.

Comment: Is there any other way to attach event handlers on elements except the jQuery `on()` function as I did? Some purely Angular approach? so that no `$apply` or `$digest` needed

Comment: the angular approach is to use `ng-click` - internally it will also use jQuery and `$scope.$apply`

Comment: Exactly. As I mentioned above, you should use the ng-click directive in your span to trigger the "toggleIsYellow" method.

Answer (score 1):

You change the value of `isYellow` in the DOM event process, but Angular updates must run in the Angular `digest` phase.

To make your example run you need to wrap the code line in an $scope.$apply function of manually run `$scope.$digest()` at the end of the update process.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Ldbocp73/

```
this.toggleIsYellow = function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.isYellow = ($scope.isYellow == 1) ? 0 : 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is nice `$scope.isYellow = !$scope.isYellow;` )